# Newspaper layout with two columns and a quotation box centered?

Tags: css, layout, css-multicolumn-layout

I’m looking for a way to create a newspaper layout for a website where the content is split into two columns but with a quotation box in the middle of the columns.

I know how to make two columns using CSS3 with the

```
-moz-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
```

But how do I create the quotation box in the middle and is there any way that I “wrap” the content inside the columns around the box in the middle?

I’ve attached an illustration of what I mean.
Please imagine in this illustration that the text in the two columns is wrapped around the box in the middle.

[image: Newsletter Layout]

Comment: See [this List Apart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crosscolumn/), which includes an option for 3-column layouts as well. (Demos are at the bottom.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that works:

[DEMO HERE](http://dabblet.com/gist/3427208)

This would give your columns flexibility. However, your quote area would have to be a fixed height/width. If you want to adjust the quote area, change the widths/heights of the spacer divs at the beginning of each column div. Not an elegant solution, but it works.

CSS:

```
#one {
    float:left;
    width:48%;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    min-height:400px;
}
#two {
    float:right;
    width:48%;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    min-height:400px;
}
#three {
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:100px;
    margin-left:-300px;
    border:1px solid;
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    background: maroon;
    color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="one">
    <div style="float: right; height: 80px; width: 10px;"></div>
    <div style="float: right; height: 210px; width: 300px; clear: both;"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="three">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </div>
<div id="two">
    <div style="float: left; height: 80px; width: 10px;"></div>
    <div style="float: left; height: 210px; width: 300px; clear: both;"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Notice: This builds upon peteris solution (which didn't wrap around the quote div) below.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's wrong but...:

```
<style>
#one {
    float:left;
    width:48%;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    min-height:400px;
}
#two {
    float:right;
    width:48%;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    min-height:400px;
}
#three {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-150px;
    margin-left:-100px;
    border:1px solid;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
</style>
<div id="one">ONE</div>
<div id="three">3</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved, but... it's not flexible, you'll have to tweak the positioning for almost any change you make to the text.

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3427016)

HTML

```
<div class='newspaper'>
    <img src='http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/8049/birmancat.jpg'>
    <p><!-- paragraph text --></p>
        <!-- nine more paragraphs -->
</div>
```

CSS I've added:

```
.newspaper {
    position: relative;
    width: 580px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
    font-size: 12px
}
p { margin: 0 0 10px; }
p:nth-child(3):before, p:nth-child(8):before {
    width: 145px;
    height: 200px;
    content: '';
}
p:nth-child(3):before {
    float: right;
}
p:nth-child(8):before {
    float: left;
}
.newspaper img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 85px; left: 50%;
    margin: 0 -150px;
}
```

Comment: Hi everyone and thanks for your input and suggestions. The examples on "alistapart" illustrates beautiful what I'm trying to accomplish but it show a very static and non-flexible solution where the length and position of the text and box is known. Would it be possible to make it dynamic, where the text is an unknown length? In these examples there are two div's and for me to fill them continuously I've to split the text-string and insert them equally into each div and then calculate the position of the box in the middle? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think I can do it with JQuery. I'll work on it and post my answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/xbfYD/4/

I modified @sean_mcgee's answer by adding some JavaScript to split the columns for you. Just place the text in the `newspaperArticle` div, and put your quote in the JavaScript field. It doesn't work well on a small screen because the words are longer than the space, so here is a full-screen example: http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/xbfYD/4/embedded/result/. The only problem is that it could split an HTML tag apart, so be careful.

Comment: I would use it with CSS3's `text-justify` property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp