# CSS: "Newspaper Author" layout with floated box and various html content

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

**GOAL:**
Trying to create this "newspaper author" layout in HTML/CSS:
[image]

**SOLUTION/PROBLEM:**
I've floated a box to the left, and I have text and various content which wraps around this box.  Problem is, some of the content has background-color and other CSS effects that spill over into the box.  How can I accomplish this layout without the spilling over problem?

```
<div id="main-content">
    <aside id="side-box">
        left-floated box.
    </aside>
    <p> 
        Various content that may have background color etc.
    </p>
</div>
```

**DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/HU277/1/

> Closest I could find to a duplicate issue:
>   [CSS: Newspaper layout with two columns and a quotation box centered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076701/css-newspaper-layout-with-two-columns-and-a-quotation-box-centered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add  `overflow: hidden;` to your H1 tag (an re style padding etc...)

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks.  However, `overflow: hidden;` prevents the wrap around effect if the element with the background color happens to extend past the bottom of the left-floated box.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HU277/2/

Comment: I've settled with this as a compromise.  Thanks!